# RewriteRule from a subdomain to parent domain directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have to reroute some JS and CSS files to a PHP file.

Currently I have:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(js|css)) /process.php?file=$1
```

Which works fine and does the job in the sub-directories. However, if it's a subdomain, it doesn't call the script and instead gives me a 404.

How can I route that call to the parent directory (public_html)?

I've also tried giving a direct route "/home/myusername/public_html/process.php?file=$1" but didn't do the job.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If your subdomain has its own VirtualHost entry, you need to add the RewriteRule to the VirtualHost definition block as well.